# Why MySQLI prepare is failing but no errors is being reported

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am stuck up as to why my Update prepare statement is failing but though I do not see any SQL error:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'\config.php' );
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
$value = $_POST['value'] ;
$column = $_POST['columnName'] ;
$columnPosition = $_POST['columnPosition'] ;
$columnId = $_POST['columnId'] ;
$rowId = $_POST['rowId'] 
$response['status']='';
$mysqli = new mysqli($sql_details['host'],$sql_details['user'],$sql_details['pass'],$sql_details['db']);
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET ? = ? where id = ?")) {
        $response['status']='OK';
        //$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $column, $value, intval(ltrim(substr($id, -4),'0')));
        //$stmt->execute(); 
        //$response['status'] = $mysqli->affected_rows;
        //if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1 )
            //$response['status'] = 'success'; 
        $stmt->close();
        //if (!$mysqli->commit())
            //$response['status'] = 'fail'; 
        $mysqli->close();
    }
    else
        $response['status']=$mysqli->error;
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Even though I have commented most of the lines and expect to the conditional string 'OK' at my UI side - I never ever see that . No errors is also reported - what am I doing wrong?

It seems that the UPDATE prepared statement works fine when in case of column name is present rather than a bind value like the below one works:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name = ? where id = ?"))
```

Is there any way to have it the way I have requested?

Comment: You cannot bind identifiers. You must whitelist them and put into the query as is instead.

Comment: But the issue is occurring prior to that - in the prepare statement cause I verified after commenting each line out in the block

Comment: That's right - you cannot bind identifiers, so the `prepare` fails.

Comment: Is there a way we can make dynamic prepare statements - the issue I see is setting the column names?

Comment: I have already mentioned it: you dynamically put whitelisted identifiers into the query. Simply using concatenation.